# How to lock some parts of Settings?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, settings, security

My android device is rooted.

Like other android devices, there are many sections in Settings Menu like

1. Wireless & Networks
2. Device
3. Personal
4. Accounts
5. Systems

And in all above sections, there are sub-sections also like following..

In **Wireless & Networks**; there are **SIM Management**, **Wi-Fi**, **Bluetooth**, **Data Usage** and **More settings …**

I would like to lock some sections and some sub-sections of Setting Menu.

Is it possible to lock Setting Menu in section-wise or subsection-wise?

Please let me know, how to do it?

Regards

GNS

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can lock sections of settings, but you can lock whole settings with app like "App locker" and others like that

Comment: I am already using this app, App Locker but I am concerned with sections of settings.

Comment: @GNS Sorry, not possible

Comment: As per many experts, after rooting an android device, an end user has completer privilege for android device. However, its really an unfortunate that I can't lock Setting Menu in section-wise or subsection-wise. I am already using App Locker.

Answer (score 0):

it all depends on the ROM you've installed. For a primary user (on any ROM) you can't lock any setting like you intend to do.

But on some ROMs like MIUI, you can create a second user, where some settings like Mobile Data, SIM Card Management, Lock Screen Settings are locked and available only for the first user. I dont know about other other ROMs but MIUI does provide an option like that